# Solving derivative of cumulative normal distribution log likelihood

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, equation-solving

I am a newbie and I'm trying to use *Mathematica* to obtain the symbolic Maximum Likelihood Estimation for a cumulative normal distribution. So far I have reached the step where I have the derivative of the log likelihood for both $\mu$ and $\sigma$, i.e. 
$ \text{score}=\left\{\frac{\partial \text{logL}}{\partial \mu },\frac{\partial \text{logL}}{\partial \sigma }\right\} 
$, or

$$
\left\{\sum _{i=1}^n -\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} e^{-\frac{\left(\mu -x_i\right){}^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sigma  \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\mu -x_i}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)},\sum _{i=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(\mu -x_i\right) e^{-\frac{\left(\mu -x_i\right){}^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sigma ^2 \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\mu -x_i}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)}\right\}
$$
The problem is that when I try to solve when these expressions are `0`:

```
Solve[score == {0, 0} && σ > 0, {μ, σ}]
```

*Mathematica* tells me that it can't solve it (Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve).

Is this really such a hard problem or am I missing something?

Comment: Try `Solve[ Thread[ score={0,0}]...]`

Comment: and please typeset `mathematica` expressions. cf the FAQ.

Comment: @chris I tried it with Thread but it still doesn't work, also it works for other distributions such as Poisson, so if Thread is just for the syntax, i don't think I have a syntax issue

Comment: What is your 'cumulative normal distribution'? Do you mean a Normal distribution, or the distribution of the sample sum, or something else?

Comment: @wolfies i mean the generic cumulative normal distribution,
CDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], x]

Comment: Eh? The CDF of the Normal is not the pdf. The MLE is calculated wrt the pdf, not the cdf.

Comment: The above solution has 2 components, the first one solves it for n elements, but the second one with use of LogLikelihood function, only does it for 3. Is it possible to make it working for n elements as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us try with a Normal distribution. Start by the log normal of it:

```
ff = PowerExpand[Log@ PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x], 
Assumptions -> {σ > 0,μ ∈  Reals,  x ∈ Reals}]
```

Now the log likelihood obey

```
Q = Sum[ff /. x -> Subscript[x, i], {i, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can define the condition of stastionarity

```
eqn = Thread[D[Q, #] & /@ {σ, μ} == 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We need to tell mathematica to expand the sums

```
eqn2 = 
 eqn /. Sum[a_, b_] :>  sum[Expand[a], b] //. 
     sum[a_ + b_, c_] :> sum[a, c] + sum[b, c] /. 
    sum[a_ b_, c_] :> b   sum[a, c] /; FreeQ[b, Subscript[x, i]] /. 
   sum[a_, b_] :> a sum[1, b] /; FreeQ[a, Subscript[x, i]] /. 
  sum -> Sum
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

now we can solve

```
Solve[eqn2, {μ, σ }][[2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

QED

**EDIT**

You might want to look at the  [LogLikelihood function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LogLikelihood.html)

With this function, taking a definite (`n=3`) case

```
Q = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 3}]]

Solve[Thread[D[Q, #] & /@ {μ, σ} == 0], {μ, σ}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With  a numerical example:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 100];

Q = LogLikelihood[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], data];

sol=NSolve[Thread[D[Q, #] & /@ {μ, σ} == 0], {μ, σ}][[2]]

(* ==> {μ-> 0.92576,  σ-> 2.03064} *)

Show[ContourPlot[Q, {μ, -1, 3}, {σ, 1, 3}, ColorFunction -> "Heat"], 
Graphics[Point[{μ, σ}] /. sol]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For a cumulative distribution? What sort of density would you suggest this cumulative distribution has?

Comment: @chris so this means that the only way to fit a dataset with normcdf is numerical optimization?

Comment: @wolfies I guess its a good point: the CDF is not normalized...

Comment: @chris thank you very much for your detailed answer :)

Comment: @chris i think after your last edit the answer ( that there is no analytic solution to the MLE of a normal cumulative distribution) is not so clear anymore. Would you consider including the previous normcdf results also?

Comment: The problem is that a normal cumulative distribution is not  a distribution as its integral diverges.